# Reg. SharePoint 2010 Content Type Syndication Doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I wanted to configure content type syndication in SharePoint 2010. I followed the following steps to configure the Content Type Hub

1. Created a Web application and root level site collection based on Team Site Site Template
2. Enabled Content Type Syndication Feature and Publishing Infrastructure feature (since i want to push page layout based content types to subscribers as well)
3. Configured the site collection Url as the content type hub in Managed Metadata service
4. Enabled "Consumes content types from the Content Type Gallery" & "Push-down Content Type Publishing updates from the Content Type Gallery to sub-sites and lists using the content type" in the Managed Metadata Service Connection

I created few site columns and a site content type in the site collection configured as Content type hub.

I created another web application and a top site collection based on publishing portal template. The Managed Metadata service was configured for the web application. The site content type created in the content type and the associated site columns are consumed in the site collection.

However, when i go ahead and create another content type or make changes to the content type it is not getting pushed into the publishing site even though the content type has been configured to publish the content type. Also, there is no errors in the Content type publishing error log as well.

Can you guys let me know what is the configuration i am missing to get the content type syndication to work?

Thanks in Advance

Cheers,
Madhu

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this same issue. It is very frustrating. 
Once I was able to 'fix' it by removing the MMS from the default group then adding it back. However, that did not work the second time I was having issues with updating syndicated content types. 
And, yes, I do have the "Refresh all published content types on next update" checkbox selected on the consuming Site Collection's Content Type Publishing setting. 
Nothing in the publishing error log.

Comment: i even tried by creating a new MMS and content hub but it didn't work. I tried the same configuration in a different environment and it worked fine. It's certainly a environment issue but the error is not getting logged anywhere.. very strange behaviour... Any bright ideas???